# Sumif function between 2 dataframes

Tags: pandas, performance, dataframe, sumifs

I have 2 dataframes like this:

| Type | Year Start | Year end | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020 | 2020 | 4 |
| A | 2019 | 2020 | 5 |
| B | 2018 | 2019 | 3 |
| C | 2017 | 2019 | 9 |

| Type | Year | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2017 | 2 |
| A | 2018 | 3 |
| A | 2019 | 1 |
| A | 2020 | 4 |
| B | 2017 | 1 |
| B | 2018 | 1 |
| B | 2019 | 2 |
| B | 2020 | 3 |
| C | 2017 | 4 |
| C | 2018 | 2 |
| C | 2019 | 3 |
| C | 2020 | 1 |

So for the first table, the field total should be the sum of the second table meeting 2 conditions (same type year >= & <=). It would be like the sumif function of excel.

So far, I have achieved this functionality by defining a function with masks and using apply over the dataframe. This approach works fine, however is very slow. Is there a way to perform this faster?

Comment: Dont post your data as pictures, no one can copy it to reproduce your question.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to have the first df as result? If not ```df['total'] = df.groupby('Type')['Amount'].transform(pd.Series.cumsum)``` does the job.

Comment: Yes as the first table is a large dataframe with many variables, and this sumif function is needed to calc just one more